# Is there a way to save results from a for loop besides using print()?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to get the results from the my For Loop and if loop. The two results I want are the optimal price and optimal product when supply=demand.

```py
def supply(p):
    """
    This function calculates the supply of the video game as a function of price
    :param P: Ideal price of the game
    :return: The result of the calculated supply
    """
    supply = 500 + 90 * p
    return supply

def demand(p):
    """
    This function calculates the demand as a function of price
    :param P: Ideal price of the game
    :return: the result of the calculated demand
    """
    demand = 10000 - 35 * p
    return demand

for p in range(10 , 161, 1):
    demand_result = supply(p)
    supply_result = demand(p)
    print('Price is:', p , 'Demand # is:' , demand_result , 'Supply # is:' , supply_result)

    if demand_result == supply_result:
        p = optimal_price
        supply_result = optimal_product

print('The optimal price is ${:.2f}'.format(optimal_price))
```

The expected result is price = $76.00 and product = 7340

Comment: What do you mean by 'save'? Do you want to save a line of text, or maybe some numbers, to a file?

Comment: python will calculate a multiplication before an addition. Also you could just put 590 * p instead of 500+90 unless your creating an input system. If that is the case you would be better creating a class

Comment: Shouldn't it be optimal_price = p (rather than p = optimal_price)?  Also, you should break the for loop in the conditional after the optimal_price is found unless you want to save the supply_result and demand_result for each price into an array.

Answer (score 0):

you can save each element into a list and then save this list into a json file that you can load your data from next time you want it.

```py
# importing the library that is necessary to deal with json files.
import json 

# opens a json file that exist in the current directory, the file is readable only. 
file = open("some_file.json", "r")

''' opens a json file that exist in the current directory, and if not, will create one, if the file already exists,
writing in it will overwrite what was already written in the file.''' 
file_1 = open("some_file_1.json", "w")

''' opens a json file that exist in the current directory, and if not, will create one, if the file already exists,
writing in it will not overwrite what was already written in the file, writing in it will append the new data.'''
file_2 = open("some_file_2.json", "a")

# writes into an already opened json file, doesn't work in mode "r" (readable), overwrites in "w" and appends in "a".
json.dump(new_data, file_1)

# returns json objects that exist in the file as dictionaries, works only on files that are opened with mode "r" (readable). 
json.load(file)

# closes the file after we finish using it.
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code provides the desired output (minimizing changes in your original code)

```
def supply(p):
    """
    This function calculates the supply of the video game as a function of price
    :param P: Ideal price of the game
    :return: The result of the calculated supply
    """
    supply = 500 + 90 * p
    return supply

def demand(p):
    """
    This function calculates the demand as a function of price
    :param P: Ideal price of the game
    :return: the result of the calculated demand
    """
    demand = 10000 - 35 * p
    return demand


for p in range(10 , 161, 1):
    demand_result = demand(p) # compute demand & supply
    supply_result = supply(p)

    #print('Price is:', p , 'Demand # is:' , demand_result, 'Supply # is:' , supply_result)

    if demand_result == supply_result: # demand meets supply
        optimal_price = p
        optimal_supply = supply_result
        break                         # break for loop since we're found match

print('The optimal price is ${:.2f}'.format(optimal_price))
print('The optimal supply is {:.2f}'.format(optimal_supply))
```

Output

```
The optimal price is $76.00
The optimal supply is 7340.00
```